# Czech Archive Ubuntu 18.04 LTS missing bionic Release

Tags: apt, 18.04, archive

After using `apt-get update` today, it tells me that `http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release` does not contain the file `Release`. And indeed, after checking http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/, I cannot find any file named `Release`.
But while checking http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/, the `Release` file is there. Does this mean that the Czech support for Ubuntu is over?

It is making impossible to work with the system right now as no PPA can be added, or any application cannot be installed.

For now I fixed the issue by removing `cz.` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. However, can I somewhere check whether this is an intended change? Or what should I do in this case?

After checking the Czech forum that can be found on the language mutation of the Ubuntu original website, I am not the only once facing this issue: https://forum.ubuntu.cz/index.php/topic,84666.0.html
However, there has not been a clear answer either yet.

Thank you in advance for a reply.

Comment: This means that Czech maintainers did something wrong. You can always switch to another mirror.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I switch to a closer Ubuntu mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682532/how-do-i-switch-to-a-closer-ubuntu-mirror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today everything seems to be okay again as before. So this comment answered my initial questions:

> This means that Czech maintainers did something wrong. You can always switch to another mirror.

I also mentioned changing the Ubuntu mirror, however, thank you for linking the related topic.