# Why am I not able to upgrade my system?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, update-manager

When I attempt to upgrade my system, with `sudo apt upgrade` I get the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libxatracker2 amd64 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker2_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

[picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehgot.png)

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: please [edit] your question indicate what you were updating from and what commands you used to achieve this.

Comment: @24601 I made some, hopefully, beneficial edits.

Comment: @user535733 When I go to the URL (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker2_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1_amd64.deb) in browser, it says "This page isn’t working archive.ubuntu.com didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: @user535733 Yeah, that's why I included a code block and an image.

Comment: @user535733 I am showing the error, in the hopes that someone may recognize it and share solutions or theories. I am not sure how my efforts have been wasted.

Comment: you still haven't said what you were upgrading from.

Comment: @24601 It's in the screenshot - an ordinary apt upgrade, not a release-upgrade

Answer (score 4):

Your output (`Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]`) suggests a problem at the server end, not your end. You cannot fix it.

Interestingly, I'm seeing some of the same problems. So among the choices below, "wait" is a viable alternative for this case.

- For many users the simplest and quickest solutions is to [try a different mirror](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682532/how-do-i-switch-to-a-closer-ubuntu-mirror).
- If that mirror has worked before, you can try simply waiting for the mirror to be fixed by the server's owner (or for access to be restored by the ISP). Mirrors do occasionally drop out briefly in order to sync. Occasionally the hosting servers come under Denial Of Service attacks. There are other temporary possibilities.
- If you are on an enterprise or school network that requires use of a proxy, contact your IT department for their proxy instructions.
- Internet Service Providers in some countries may restrict access to Ubuntu Mirrors due to mistakes or policy. Sometimes the restriction is for something else that's hosted on the same server. You can contact your ISP and ask them if they are restricting access to that IP address.

Comment: I agree. After waiting for some time, in addition to trying different mirrors, the issue persists!