# Unable to update ubuntu 12.04.5 to latest version

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I'm new to Ubuntu, trying to update Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS to latest version and unable to do it.

Error:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release No new release found
```

Comment: @ElderGeek i'm not sure what exactly to modify there

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Nobody wants to retype this to see if google has something interesting on it. Please copy/paste the text. Open the 1st file it mentions with gedit or vi and look at line 9. It seems to contain a value of <test> and that is not valid. Removing the fonts is probably an options too :)

Comment: By the way: these are all warnings and those should not stop you from updating(?) Only "critical" and "error" notice should stop the update.

Comment: @Rinzwind  thanks for the suggestion.  The update manager says the software on this computer is up to date
The package information was just updated but the version still shows 12.04.5

Comment: But then all is taking care of? You updated 12.04.5 to the latest changes. If you want to upgrade to 14.04 I would expected you to do  `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind i did actually tried that and the response is as below

Comment: nren@nren-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d

[sudo] password for nren: 

Checking for a new Ubuntu release

No new release found

nren@nren-Inspiron-3542:~$

Comment: @naren you should [edit] that into your post along with the text to replace your image. Be that as it may you might want to choose a [different mirror](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror) to resolve "No new release found"

Answer (score 1):

Personally never had a problem running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by finding an up-to-date mirror near you from [this list.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Select the mirror you've chosen by selecting it from Software & Updates Ubuntu software tab as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/37825/225694)

Issue the `sudo do-release-upgrade` command.

This commadn has a number of switches that modify it's actions that you can review with the command `man do-release-upgrade`

the -d switch as shown in your post indicates:

```
Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible
```

Another option is the -p switch which indicates:

```
Try upgrading to the latest release using the upgrader from Ubuntu-proposed
```

**My preferred method of upgrading** is often referred to as the *clean install* Which includes [backing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172) my home directory (I use a seperate partition for home to make this simple) and [Installing fresh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) the version I want over [or alongside if space is available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) my existing installation.