# While updating Ubuntu from terminal, Fetching repository list timed out

Tags: networking, apt

While updating Ubuntu 16.04, I face the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://172.0.1.201/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 172.0.1.201:80 (172.0.1.201), connection timed out
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Why did you use repository from `172.0.1.201`? It is much better to use repositories that is offical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `172.0.1.201` is currently down.

Open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` using `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and replace `http://172.0.1.201/` with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/`.