# Installation problem of openssh client and openssh server and some packages during system update

Tags: updates, ssh, system

I am trying to install the OpenSSH client on my Ubuntu system since I still receive the following error message:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Openssh-client package is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: 'openssh-client' package has no installation candidate
```

I checked several forums and thought it was a problem updating my system. So I tried to update and I get this message that some packages can not be installed. I do not know what to do. Here is the answer:

```
Err http://sunsite.rediris.es xenial Release.gpg
  Can not resolve "sunsite.rediris.es"
Err http://sunsite.rediris.es xenial-updates Release.gpg
  Can not resolve "sunsite.rediris.es"
Err http://sunsite.rediris.es xenial-backports Release.gpg
  Can not resolve "sunsite.rediris.es"
Err http://sunsite.rediris.es xenial-security Release.gpg
  Can not resolve "sunsite.rediris.es"
W: Can not retrieve http://sunsite.rediris.es/mirror/ubuntu-archive/dists/xenial/InRelease
W: The download of some index files failed, they were skipped, or the old ones were used instead.
```

Comment: Looks like you need to choose a different mirror: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Answer (score 4):

You need a different mirror. This mirror no longer exists. Choose a new mirror - I won't go into detail about that here, that is out of scope of this question. Have a look at [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror).

Select your mirror and open a Terminal. Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then you can install `openssh-client`.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```