# GUI feature missing from full ubuntu installation 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, xorg, gui, gdm

I encountered multiple problems installing libraries (to python) that have many dependencies..at some point I think it just crashed,

now it boots only to terminal window starting from login. Meanwhile, I relocated to many places, so the internet is lost.

Can anyone guide me:

1. to connecting the internet, (I can't get the `ip route` to return anything, `ifconfig` to work without `net-tools` that must be installed using `sudo apt`, which requires internet..oh the vicious cycle)

   > resolved with the command

   ```
   nmcli dev wifi connect <mySSID> password <myPassword>
   ```
2. reviving the GUI features that normally worked .. I didn't install server version obviously.

   > Tried:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```

   from [Fix user interface (Ubuntu Unity) disappearing problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.fosslinux.com/537/fix-user-interface-ubuntu-unity-disappearing-problem-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04.htm)

`DISPLAY:=0 ccsm &` directs me to a library gtk under python2.7. 
Returned a msg in line with `Nonetype cannot bring default screen`

when running `sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing`

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdm3/libgdm1_3.28.2-0ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb 404 Not Found & the like, grub2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First get your packages sorted out**

If you are getting errors downloading packages, you need to enable mirrors:

[How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Then run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing
```

This should fix any broken things with apt and your package library.

**Next, reinstall the GUI**

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session gdm3
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

**Start the X server**

You can now reboot or start the server manually to make sure it works:

```
startx
```

Comment: really, but its a record of trial-and-error