# Stuck on terminal instead of GUI in Ubuntu 20.04.4 , on Virtual Machine VMWARE

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gui, vmware, vmware-workstation

I've had a big problem and can't resolve it even with Google's help..

I'm stuck on the terminal / shell from Ubuntu; which is on VMWARE Workstation on Windows 10.

I would like to get the GUI / interface GNOME I think, back.

I was at first on the GUI, I started to lose internet connection but I didn't care.

But after the VM "locked" itself, i tried to get back on it with my password but the keyboard didn't work.

So I restarted it but it was the shell/terminal view and not the GUI..

I had python 2.7 and 3.8 installed by myself, I had to uninstall python3.8 (I had a problem by running Matlab with it so I tried to get only one version of python needed from the application I was using).

I've read that the purge of python might be the origin of the problem of the GUI; and that I just had few commands to do to switch back to the GUI, but these commands require "sudo install or upgrade or update..." like:

"

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

"

I wanted to do everything on that page :
[GUI feature missing from full ubuntu installation 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066048/gui-feature-missing-from-full-ubuntu-installation-18-04?rq=1)
but I haven't internet on the vmware now so I cannot do anything I get "Erreur temporaire de résolution "us.archive.ubuntu.com" for every package i try to install or update or upgrade

If anyone has a clue for this ? :3

PS: the host has internet ..

Thanks

Comment: Did you boot into a root shell prompt **with networking**? You need networking to access the repos over the internet

Answer (score 0):

2 options.

The first one (and less likely to work) is to get into a tty and type `nmtui` to access Network Manager TUI and use that to connect to the internet, then you should be able to execute the `apt` commands you are trying to run.

The second one is to boot into a live session of Ubuntu (using Ubuntu iso) and chroot into your root folder. From there you can do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`