# how to install package from a specific mirror ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, source-packages

I have a package I want to install (libproxy1-plugin-webkit) however it keeps trying to connect a specific mirror that I can't connect to. I tried adding a few other mirrors that were listed in [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror) to the top of my /etc/apt/sources.list file but still the same. So how can I tell it to use one of the other mirrors?

Comment: Have you removed the old entry and, after that, ran `apt-get update`?

Comment: DON'T add multiple mirrors of the same repository. Apt assumes that you, the human, have selected the mirror that you want it to use. It won't choose for you.

Comment: Is there no way to specify which mirror I want to use without removing the old entries?