# New install of Ubuntu 18.04.5 server - Unable to do apt updates

Tags: apt, updates

Having previously installed an Ubuntu 18.04 server I expected no problems with using the `sudo apt update` command.  However my recent install of Ubuntu 18.04.5 has a problem installing updates using the `apt` command, it simply doesn't seem to work for anything allowing standard package installations/updates/upgrades.

I subsequently modified my sources.list file to attempt to install webmin and that did allow me to download from the source site for that package.

I then tried pinging the `sources.list` sites which are in the `sources.list` file, and was successful in returning pings from those sites.

Still after that webmin package download I was not able to successfully use the `sudo apt update` command.  I received the following messages:

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to banjo.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to kazooie.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to banjo.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to kazooie.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
...
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am wondering if anyone has seen this problem and if anyone has suggestion towards a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or something that filters HTTP traffic destinations?  This sounds like a firewall is blocking your connecting over HTTP to the servers for the repositories.

Comment: I do have an outside facing router and firewall but, I have placed the server in question on the DMZ and still have had no success in updating/upgrading/installing packages using the "apt" or "apt-get" command from cli.

Answer (score 0):

This problem affected my whole network and was solved when my ISP rebooted equipment associated with my service.

Consider this problem solved not as an Ubuntu issue but rather one due to my ISP.

Thank you to those who sought to help me.