# WineHQ installation failed

Tags: wine

I installed the lastest stable Ubuntu (today is 22.3.2022, so it's 20.04.3 LTS). - a fresh installation.

I went to the WineHQ webpage, filled all the requests.

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

then I finally come to install...

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

it starts out normally - asking me a [y / n] question, I say y.

Then 110 errors appear - all of the same type, let's see the first one:

```
Err:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 libcrypt1 i386 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
```

then another stack of errors appear - all of the same type, let's see the first one:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.10-10ubuntu4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
```

then a comp. suggestion:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

What seems to be the officer?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lc0sA2WsCgY

Comment: it seems it has problem to get data from server `il.archive.ubuntu.com` - maybe it doesn't have this repo. If you would use GUI like synaptic then you could easy select different mirror server in different location/country. Sometimes some servers may not have all repos or they need time to get fresh versions.

Comment: False assumption that only LTS releases are "stable". All releases of Ubuntu are tested by a large team of volunteers before release and are stable.

Comment: Unless you have a specific need for the latest version of wine, undo everything you did and just install the version from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: The *lastest stable* release of Ubuntu is 2021-October release; ie. 21.10 and not four releases ago or the 2020-April (20.04) system. The 20.04 system you mention is also not the latest (*of the 4 releases ago 20.04*) either, see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ though installed systems upgraded weeks before that date which is the ISO release date (*a re-spin of the older 20.04 release with fixes applied & new kernel stack from 21.10*)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has problem to download `libcrypt1` from server `il.archive.ubuntu.com`

When I try to download manually in browser then I also can't get it.

http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.10-10ubuntu4_i386.deb

But I don't have problem when I use address ie. for GB or PL

http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.10-10ubuntu4_i386.deb

Maybe it is fresh version and it wasn't resend to all mirror servers - and you may need to wait few hours/days or you may change mirror server.

---

If you use some GUI to install programs (like `synaptic`, `Software Sources`) then you could select new mirror server from list.

You may also change it like in other question

[repository - How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Comment: You're correct! You've solved it! Thank you furas! I installed Synaptic, went to 'Settings', 'Repositories', 'Download from:', changed it from Server of Israel to Main Server, went to install WineHQ from their main site - installation done! - I have Wine, cheers!

Comment: if it resolved your problem then you can mark my answer as accepted.