# Can't upgrade to Ubuntu 22: 404 not found

Tags: 22.04

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 20 to Ubuntu 22 via Software Updates.
I have already updated and upgraded through both apt and apt-get.
However, the Ubuntu upgrade keeps failing under the following errors:

```
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12-base_12-20220319-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libgcc-s1_12-20220319-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.27-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2_2.44-1build3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgpg-error/libgpg-error0_1.43-3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt20/libgcrypt20_1.9.4-3ubuntu3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lz4/liblz4-1_1.9.3-2build2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xz-utils/liblzma5_5.2.5-2ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libz/libzstd/libzstd1_1.4.8+dfsg-3build1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd0_249.11-0ubuntu3.4_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5support0_1.19.2-2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.19.2-2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/keyutils/libkeyutils1_1.6.1-2ubuntu3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-3_1.19.2-2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libgssapi-krb5-2_1.19.2-2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnsl/libnsl2_1.3.0-2build2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.12.20-2ubuntu4_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libunistring/libunistring2_1.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.3.2-2build1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gamemode/libgamemode0_1.6.1-1build2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gamemode/libgamemodeauto0_1.6.1-1build2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnss-nis/libnss-nis_3.1-0ubuntu6_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnss-nisplus/libnss-nisplus_1.3-0ubuntu6_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
```

I know for sure that this is not a weak connection issue, as I have tried this under several networks.
How can I fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have an old 32 bit install?  I see a lot of i386. Ubuntu discontinued 32 bit several versions ago as systems have been 64 bit for years. Some may have had 32 bit Windows, but were 64 bit. What does this show? `uname -a` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo | head -10`

Comment: I tested a couple random packages on that list: Each `404` error does NOT mean a bad connection. It means there is no 32-bit (i386) package. @oldfred is right.

Comment: @oldfred That would make sense. I received my machine with a few packages already installed, so those are probably the 32-bit ones (I don't think I have installed any 32-bit packages myself). The first command's output is ```Linux Lenovo-V510 5.4.0-124-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 02:23:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux```. I know for certain that the machine itself is 64-bit based. Is there any way to check what 32-bit packages are installed and/or remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a not up-to-date update server mirror that isn't serving you the packages that you need to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. The Main Ubuntu update server works fine for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12-base_12-20220319-1ubuntu1_i386.deb - [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/9491).

A standard sources.list file at `/etc/apt/sources.list` for Ubuntu 20.04 using the Main server looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

After changing the update server mirror  run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.

Comment: That would make sense. The problem is, that I received the machine with several packages already installed, and those are probably the 32-bit ones (I don't think that I made any 32-bit installations myself). Is there any way to check what 32-bit packages are installed and/or remove them?

Comment: You already know which i386 packages are blocking the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, and all  of these packages are listed in your question. There may be other i386 packages installed, but they are not blocking the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 so you don't need to uninstall them.

Comment: @aviad1 Look at the links: For example, the first link `http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12-base_12-20220319-1ubuntu1_i386.deb` belongs to the package `gcc-12-base`. You can try `apt search gcc-120-base` to search this name in the repository to confirm it. This works similarly for the other links.

Comment: Furthermore, `apt rdepends --installed` lists the reverse dependencies of a package (which installed software depends on the package) and `apt purge` removes a package.

Comment: You're using a bad update server mirror that isn't serving you the packages that you need to upgrade. The Main Ubuntu update server works fine for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12-base_12-20220319-1ubuntu1_i386.deb - [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/9491)