# I'm getting 403 forbidden error when I'm trying to update on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Here's the command and output on my terminal:

```
~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
[sudo] password for paulo: 
Err:1 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Err:4 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Err:5 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.184.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Entering the urls with error on web browser does result 403 code and the message is

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

Comment: Try a different mirror: https://askubuntu.com/a/37825/19626

Answer (score 0):

Search for Software&Updates, select download from: other.. Then select best server. Wait.