# slow package installed in ubuntu server

Tags: 20.04

I have 16 gb ram server  running ubuntu 20.04 barely use 2 gb also server load is 4  or less
network speed is  also so good +500 mb
but when i try to install any package using apt install it so slow it's takes forever to install
what can cuase slow package install using apt install anything  etc ....

Comment: Are your network settings properly configured? I've had similar issues with improperly set DNS server. If that's not the problem then I'd also take a look at which package server mirror is apt using and then try a different mirror to see if it works better. Check the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror) to see how to do that.

Comment: You are asking "*What can cause XYZ?*" You are asking for a list of possible causes, which might not really be a satisfying answer. Consider a more specific question like "*How can I diagnose XYZ and improve performance?*" that might provide specific, helpful, and satisfying answers.