# Upgrade to 22.10 failed (do-release-upgrade)

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I tried `do-release-upgrade` and it failed (again!). Not sure what I'm doing wrong as it has mostly worked in the past. These are the log files from `/var/log/dist-upgrade`:

[apt.log](https://controlc.com/b03e0018)
[main.log](https://controlc.com/78eed475)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Ubuntu 22.04.1

Edit (as requested)

apt-mark showhold:

```
snapd
ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

---

Okay. I unheld those packages and updated my system and ran do-release-upgrade again. And I got the same error as last time:

```
Updating repository information

No valid mirror found 

While scanning your repository information no mirror entry for the 
upgrade was found. This can happen if you run an internal mirror or 
if the mirror information is out of date. 

Do you want to rewrite your 'sources.list' file anyway? If you choose 
'Yes' here it will update all 'jammy' to 'kinetic' entries. 
If you select 'No' the upgrade will cancel.
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1437760/edit) your question to show us the complete output of `apt-mark showhold`

Comment: Logs appear to suggest that your system is not up-to-date, or at least that your package manager already has preexisting problems. You can't release upgrade in these conditions.  Please edit your question and include the output of both `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Your output suggest multiple or cascading/sequential problems. Your initial problem packages marked "hold". Your subsequent problem is a bad mirror (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753).

Answer (score 0):

Your apt.log output says...

```
  Hold prevents MarkInstall of ubuntu-desktop:amd64 < 1.481 @hi mK NPb IPb >
  Hold prevents MarkInstall of ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.481 @hi mK NPb IPb >
```

...which suggests that you have packages that have been *marked* "Hold". Such marking specifically prevents upgrading, including release-upgrading.

Your apt-mark output confirms that you have three packages marked "hold:"

```
snapd
ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

We don't know why you marked those packages to never be upgraded, but that's the source of your current problem.

1. Release the hold on those three packages:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold snapd ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

2. Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to capture any upgrades required for the release-upgrade.
3. Finally, run `do-release-upgrade` again.

Comment: To be honest I don’t remember doing that AT ALL. I mean, why would I? Ugh. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Updating repository information

No valid mirror found

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753 for several solutions to your mirror issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same warning when updating a virtual server running on the Gandi service by commanding `do-release-upgrade`. In my case, the exact error was:

```
No valid mirror found

While scanning your repository information no mirror entry for the
upgrade was found. This can happen if you run an internal mirror or
if the mirror information is out of date.

Do you want to rewrite your 'sources.list' file anyway? If you choose
'Yes' here it will update all 'focal' to 'jammy' entries.
If you select 'No' the upgrade will cancel.
```

But I simply answered "y" to go ahead and try the update (after taking a snapshot of the disk, for safety), and everything went fine. I think the `do-release-upgrade` must have updated the mirror information. In fact, after the upgrade, the contents of the server's `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory was

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 2017-05-15 14:48 ubuntu-xenial-backports.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 70 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial-gandi.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial-gandi.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69 2017-08-19 19:50 ubuntu-xenial-gandi.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 2017-05-15 14:48 ubuntu-xenial-proposed.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 91 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial-security.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 91 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial-security.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 92 2017-08-19 19:50 ubuntu-xenial-security.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 90 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial-updates.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 90 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial-updates.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 91 2017-08-19 19:50 ubuntu-xenial-updates.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 82 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 82 2023-07-03 11:18 ubuntu-xenial.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 83 2017-08-19 19:50 ubuntu-xenial.list.save
```

and, to take an example, the content of `ubuntu-xenial.list` is now

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://mirrors.gandi.net/ubuntu/ jammy main multiverse universe
```

while that of `ubuntu-xenial.list.distUpgrade` is

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://mirrors.gandi.net/ubuntu/ focal main multiverse universe
```

and that of `ubuntu-xenial.list.save` is

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://mirrors.gandi.net/ubuntu/ xenial main multiverse universe
```

I think the "xenial" is a holdover from the first installation of Ubuntu I did in 2017 (16.04 is codenamed Xenial Xerus), while "focal" is the version I upgraded from (20.04, or "Focal Fossa"), and "jammy" is the version I upgraded to (22.04, or "Jammy Jellyfish").

**Edited to add, on 2023-07-19:**

I queried Gandi's customer about the warning, and they gave the following advice:

*Before do-release-upgrade you could uninstall the following package:*

```
apt remove gandi-hosting-vm2
```

*and then after the do-release-upgrade, reinstall the package:*

```
apt install gandi-hosting-vm2
```