# do-release-upgrade fails with many broken packages

Tags: gnome, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I was trying to update from focal fosa to jammy, but got

```
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
```

I checked [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437760/upgrade-to-22-10-failed-do-release-upgrade) which suggest holds might be a problem but

```
apt-mark showhold
```

returns nothing

I tried with the GUI to deactivate the ppa links but it also didn't work

[image]

I went to check `/var/log/dist-upgrade` as suggested in the error and I have A TON of broken

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 < 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.6 @ii mK > (< 21.04)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Breaks on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mK > (< 3.37)
Broken fuse3:amd64 Breaks on fuse:amd64 < 2.9.9-3 -> 2.9.9-5ubuntu3 @ii umU >
Broken gnome-remote-desktop:amd64 Depends on libfreerdp-server2-2:amd64 < none | 2.6.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.3 @un uH > (>= 2.5.0)
Broken libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 Conflicts on libappindicator3-1:amd64 < 12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1 -> 12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umU >
Broken libtss2-mu0:amd64 Breaks on libtss2-esys0:amd64 < 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii mK > (< 3.0.1-2)
Broken libobjc4:amd64 Depends on libgc1:amd64 < none | 1:8.0.6-1.1build1 @un uH > (>= 1:7.2d)
Broken exfatprogs:amd64 Conflicts on exfat-utils:amd64 < 1.3.0-1 @ii mK >
Broken guile-2.2-libs:amd64 Depends on libgc1:amd64 < none | 1:8.0.6-1.1build1 @un uH > (>= 1:7.4.2)
Broken libgupnp-av-1.0-3:amd64 Breaks on libgupnp-av-1.0-2:amd64 < 0.12.11-2 @ii mK > (< 0.14)
Broken gir1.2-unity-7.0:amd64 Conflicts on gir1.2-unity-5.0:amd64 < 7.1.4+19.04.20190319-0ubuntu3 @ii mK >
Broken libobjc-9-dev:amd64 Depends on libobjc4:amd64 < 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @ii umR > (>= 9.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
Broken libsepol-dev:amd64 Breaks on libsepol1-dev:amd64 < 3.0-1ubuntu0.1 @ii mK Ib > (< 3.2)
Broken libgupnp-dlna-2.0-4:amd64 Breaks on libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3:amd64 < 0.10.5-4 @ii mK > (< 0.12)
Broken libobjc-11-dev:amd64 Depends on libobjc4:amd64 < 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @ii umR > (>= 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
Broken libnode72:amd64 Breaks on libnode64:amd64 < 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libgcc1:amd64 Depends on gcc-10-base:amd64 < 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 -> 10.4.0-4ubuntu1~22.04 @ii umU > (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04)
Broken gvfs-bin:amd64 Depends on gvfs-common:amd64 < 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 -> 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1)
Broken libwacom2:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 -> 2.2.0-1 @ii umU > (= 1.3-2ubuntu3)
Broken libgsl23:amd64 Depends on libgslcblas0:amd64 < 2.5+dfsg-6build1 -> 2.7.1+dfsg-3 @ii umU > (= 2.5+dfsg-6build1)
Broken inkscape:amd64 Depends on libgsl23:amd64 < 2.5+dfsg-6build1 @ii mR > (>= 2.5)
Broken libavresample4:amd64 Depends on libavutil56:amd64 < 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 -> 7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU > (= 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1)
Broken python3.8-venv:amd64 Depends on python3.8-distutils:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mR > (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken libclang-10-dev:amd64 Depends on libobjc-9-dev:amd64 < 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 | 9.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 @ii umR >
Broken libsemanage1:amd64 Depends on libsemanage-common:amd64 < 3.0-1build2 -> 3.3-1build2 @ii umU > (= 3.0-1build2)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-remote-desktop:amd64 < none | 42.7-0ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 42)
Broken libclang-14-dev:amd64 Depends on libobjc-11-dev:amd64 < none | 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 @ii umR >
Broken libclang-dev:amd64 Depends on libclang-14-dev:amd64 < none | 1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 14~)
Broken rstudio:amd64 Depends on libclang-dev:amd64 < 1:10.0-50~exp1 | 1:14.0-55~exp2 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-remote-desktop:amd64 Depends on libfreerdp-server2-2:amd64 < none | 2.6.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2.3 @un uH > (>= 2.5.0)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-remote-desktop:amd64 < none | 42.7-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 42)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libwacom2:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 @ii gR > (>= 1.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center-data:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 -> 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6 @ii umU > (< 1:3.37)
Broken libwacom2:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 -> 2.2.0-1 @ii umU > (= 1.3-2ubuntu3)
Broken libwacom9:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 | 2.2.0-1 @ii umH > (= 2.2.0-1)
Broken libmutter-10-0:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < none | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (= 42.5-0ubuntu1)
Broken libwacom-bin:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken libinput-bin:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < none | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 42~beta)
Broken libinput10:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 < none | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 42.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 | 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umR > (>= 3.37.0)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 | 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umR > (>= 3.29)
Broken gdm3:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 | 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.37.0)
Broken update-manager:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken update-notifier:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (< 43)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.33)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.38)
Broken xserver-xorg-input-libinput:amd64 Depends on libinput10:amd64 < 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.3 | 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.2 @ii umH > (>= 1.19.1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 < 33.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42-2~fakesync1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 < 68ubuntu1~20.04.1 | 72~ubuntu5.22.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-session:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH Ib > (< 40)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii gR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-common:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on mutter:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii gR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umU > (= 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-bin:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 -> 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.37)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-common:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 -> 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1)
Broken libgweather-3-16:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 40.4-1~)
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 3.38.6)
Broken gir1.2-gweather-3.0:amd64 Depends on libgweather-3-16:amd64 < 3.36.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 | 40.0-5build1 @ii umH > (>= 40.0)
Broken gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 42~alpha)
Broken yaru-theme-gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 42~)
Broken gnome-startup-applications:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-bin:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umH > (>= 42.0-1ubuntu2)
Broken gjs:amd64 Depends on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (= 1.72.2-0ubuntu1)
Broken ubuntu-settings:amd64 Depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umH > (>= 40)
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umH > (>= 42~beta)
Broken gnome-calendar:amd64 Depends on libgweather-3-16:amd64 < 3.36.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 | 40.0-5build1 @ii umH > (>= 40.0)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 Breaks on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 1.68.4-1+b1)
Broken evolution-data-server:amd64 Depends on libgweather-3-16:amd64 < 3.36.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 | 40.0-5build1 @ii umH > (>= 40.0)
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH Ib > (< 3.38.6)
Broken gnome-todo:amd64 Depends on evolution-data-server:amd64 < 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 | 3.44.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.17.1)
Broken gnome-calendar:amd64 Depends on libgweather-3-16:amd64 < 3.36.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 | 40.0-5build1 @ii umH > (>= 40.0)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 Breaks on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 1.68.4-1+b1)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on evolution-data-server:amd64 < 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 | 3.44.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.33.1)
Broken evolution-data-server:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 -> 3.44.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.36.5-0ubuntu1)
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 3.38.6)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 Breaks on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 1.68.4-1+b1)
Broken evolution-data-server:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 -> 3.44.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.36.5-0ubuntu1)
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH Ib > (< 3.38.6)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 Breaks on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 1.68.4-1+b1)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on evolution-data-server:amd64 < 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 | 3.44.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.33.1)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1~)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (< 3.37)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.33)
```

I know I put a bunch of stuff in this machine, any advice on going back to "original state" to allow for upgrade?

Other than running ppa-purge one by one and trying to upgrade, is there any alternative?

---

This is my current setup

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: What release are you trying to upgrade?

Comment: Fastest way to go back to original state is a fresh install. Since you have to remove all the unofficial packages and reinstall them in the upgraded system later, you safe a lot of time installing 22.04 fresh and then customize it depending on your needs. Or stay with 20.04, you have still 2 years of support left.

Comment: Since your list of sources suggests that you want to run newer software, consider trying the 6-month releases of Ubuntu instead (like 22.10) so you don't need all those extra sources that break your system.

Comment: ended up biting the bullet and doing ppa-purge. I started with remmina (`sudo ppa-purge ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
`) because [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288704/problems-removing-ppa-using-ppa-purge-for-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04) faced similar issues and the install proceeded normally with a bunch of Y/N for configs that had modified (e.g., stop looking for printers in network).

Answer (score 1):

It took a while and some frustration but:

1. I went for `ppa-purge` remmina as my comment says
2. Install went fine with a few Y/N questions

After reboot, I was trapped in the [Log in loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229821/login-loop-after-installing-20-04).

I checked all the posts about it and my permissions looked fine, I didn't have `lightdm` and installing it only created problems (e.g., I was booting into terminal instead of UI). I uninstalled lightdm and continued checking for options.

Ever since I installed chrome-remote-desktop, my Ubuntu experience has been a nightmare of asking permissions for doing everything (log in, files, mount a USB flashdrive, ...). As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235971/888422) the login loop can be related to chrome-remote-desktop. After:

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome-remote-desktop
```

I could finally log into the desktop version of jammy.

---

Because I had deactivated all ppa, some of that software was not installed in the new ubuntu release (e.g., inkscape). Rstudio was also not installed

---

Software that was installed and not functioning also needed

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```