# Failed to fetch after updating to ubuntu 23.04

Tags: updates

Im on vult server. LiteSpeed CyberPanel installed.
After updating to Ubuntu 23.04 I'm starting to getting this error when I try to update:

```
root@roble:~# sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 https://mirror.insacom.cl/mariadb/repo/11.0/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Ign:4 http: same as previous lunar-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http:same as previous lunar-backports InRelease
Ign:1 deleted due to post restriction /mariadb/repo/11.0/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Ign:2 deleted due to post restriction lunar-security InRelease
Ign:3 deleted due to post restriction lunar InRelease
Ign:4 deleted due to post restriction lunar-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Ign:1 deleted due to post restriction lunar InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Ign:3 deleted due to post restriction lunar InRelease
Ign:4 deleted due to post restriction lunar-updates InRelease
Ign:5 deleted due to post restriction lunar-backports InRelease
Err:1 https://mirror.insacom.cl/mariadb/repo/11.0/ubuntu lunar InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirror.insacom.cl'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 deleted due to post restriction lunar InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 deleted due to post restriction lunar-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 deleted due to post restriction lunar-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lunar/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch deleted due to post restriction  Temporary failure resolving 'us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch deleted due to post restriction  Temporary failure resolving 'us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch deleted due to post restriction  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch deleted due to post restriction  Temporary failure resolving 'mirror.insacom.cl'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I read other posts, and checked `sources.list` and seems to be ok. Checked links and works fine.

I make a `ping` and get this error:

```
root@roble:~# ping us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com
ping: us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
root@roble:~# ping ubuntu.com
ping: ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)