# Slow Download speed

Tags: internet

good night! Before all, sorry for my bad English, actually I speak Spanish.

Well, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in my Dell InspironN7710 two weeks ago, and I've been trying to download files and software from the Browser (Firefox) and the software store of Ubuntu but it takes an eternity, I want to clarify that it doesn't happen when I try to download something else from others programs, for example, I didn't have this problem while I tried to install games from Steam, besides, I neither have problems with my internet connection in others devices (A Windows PC and cellphones) in which the Dowland speed is approximately 90MBps, but the Dowland speed in my Ubuntu PC is around 85kBps. I was looking for a solution in YouTube and others internet forums, but there are only for different Linux distros and old versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)